# Subscriptions - SSRS 2005 - Dont send report if there is no data

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have created a subscription by adding a 'TO' Email address, 'CC' Email address and specified a parameter. I don't want a report to be sent if there is no dta. I want this done by normal subscription and not Data Driven subscription. Is this possible? i thought there would be a simple tick  box or some sort.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a procedure you can use to trigger a report subscription, reportserver.dbo.addevent. create a procedure that checks if there is data  and conditionally calls this addevent procedure. remove schedules from your subscriptions and schedule your procedure instead.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying. Is there any other way this can be done? I was thinking of adding two queries, once that counts and that just brings the results.

Comment: Nevermind, I have solved the problem. I just had to create a data driven subscription and write a query, so only the user which contain the data will get sent through email. Thanks for your help.